# How would you write a .htaccess and php file with these functions?

Tags: php, .htaccess

1. Protects User directory
2. Prompts Authentication Request upon directory being accessed, and saves all attempts to log in, correct or incorrect(saves user/pass/ip used)
3. Saves these attempts in a file

Here's what I'm coming up with that just flat out doesnt work:

```
AuthUserFile /protect/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Tester's test test"
AuthType Basic

ErrorDocument 401 /log_request.php
```

The .htaccess file doesnt even redirect to my designated log_request.php. Just does a standard 401 error message.

Comment: Does your host have .htaccess files enabled?

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

1. You're missing `Require valid-user` line in your code
2. You need to exclude `log_request.php` for basic authentication

Try this code:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!log_request\.php).*$">
  AuthUserFile /protect/.htpasswd
  AuthName "Tester's test test"
  AuthType Basic
  Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 401 /log_request.php
```